# Detecting Changes in a Javascript Function's Code

Tags: javascript, prototype, javascript-objects

I need to check if a javascript function has been modified by someone overwriting its prototype, or some other way.

For example:

`var calc = function(x,y) { return x * y; }`

How can I get the code for calc (`function(x,y) { return x * y; }`) and save it as a string.

I tried:

```
calc.prototype.toString
calc.toString
```

But that seems to do something entirely different, it always returns:

```
toString() { [native code] }
```

Comment: try `calc.toString()`

Comment: Are you implementing php in your code?

Comment: @Erlisar Vasquez no, but other languages, why would that affect client side actions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Function.prototype.toString` is a function, you're looking at the code of `toString` rather than your function:

```
calc.toString()
```

Is what you're looking for.